# How to set the icon-size in a QTreeWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

How does one set the icon size for items within a Qtreewidget? So far I have tried

`QTreeWidget.setIconSize(QSize(32,32))`

But all that does is increase the width, not the height.

However, a

`print QTreeWidget.iconSize()`

shows the correct result :
`PyQt4.QtCore.QSize(32, 32)`

Does anyone have a better understanding of how QTreewidget works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jason had some of the solution. The height of the treeview's rows needs to be resized as well:

```
class MyDelegate(QItemDelegate):      
    def __init__(self):    
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self)  

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):  
        return QSize(32,32)
```

Then, elsewhere:

```
delegate = MyDelegate()   
tree = QTreeWidget()
tree.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Not ideal as it resizes every row.

[edit] If you want to vary the size of the rows ensure the QTreeWidget/View.uniformRowHeights == False

Then mess around using the index. For me I wanted the 2nd row to bigger than the rest. I'm sure there's a better way but my sizeHint became:

```
def sizeHint(self,option,index):
    parent = index.parent()
    if parent.isValid() and  not parent.parent().isValid():            
        return QSize(32,32)
    return QSize(24,24)
```

However, there's another issue with this. Icons are not resizeable. Ah! That has to be done with

`QTreeWidget.setIconSize(QSize(width,height))`

Comment: This is very helpfull! Thanks. Curiously how can I signal that delegate sizeHint? If I have a button inside my QTreeWidgetItem that I'd like to click to refresh the widget height/size. How can I link it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you need to adjust the row height of the QTreeView to accommodate the larger icons.  From what I can see in the pictures, it looks like the icons are being resized properly, but because the rows are not tall enough and the icons are being cropped.  See [this](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_can_i_change_the_row_height_of_a_qtreeview) for how to change the row heights.

Comment: Cheers,that really helped. Although not entirely perfect; I only need the 2nd level (album-level) to be bigger. So far I get every row to be bigger although I reckon with some extra research/experimentation I might be able to sort that out.

Comment: You will have to override the sizeHint() function of your item delegate.  You can tell where you are in the tree from the `QModelIndex` that is passed into the `sizeHint()` function and return the bigger size if at the 2nd level.  You can test if your at the 2nd level by testing whether or not `index.parent()` returns an empty `QModelIndex()` or not.

Comment: I tried using the QModelIndex being returned but the index is always the same. print index.parent().data().toString() always show's the same thing; nothing. Could be going about this all wrong though; just found this: QTreeWidgetItem.setSizeHint (self, int column, QSize size)

Comment: Nope, QTreeWidgetItem.setSizeHint (self, int column, QSize size) does nothing. Continuing from my previous comment, index.internalId() always shows the same value.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I tried to use a qtreeview and populate it using QStandardItemModel/Items and they function as normal. However, the QItemDelegate.sizeHint is only ever called once. Expanding trees don't call the hint so the row heights are still fixed.

Comment: Do you by any chance have the `UniformRowHeights()` property set to true in the `QTreeView`?  This would cause only one call to the sizeHint().

Comment: Jason, i found that out just after I sent my last reply. I updated my answer with that very crucial requirement.